# In QGIS, how to input & select multiple values from GUI? (without repetitive OR, OR, OR)

Tags: qgis, postgis, sql, array

In QGIS, most likely from the SELECT FEATURES BY VALUE...(F3) or SELECT FEATURES BY EXPRESSION...(CTRL-F3), what is the simplest most flexible way to put in multiple values and have QGIS show that selection on the canvas?

I have list of comma separated values which are the values of features I want to select from a spatial dataset. `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`. Because it might be a series of 50 values, I want to quickly paste that into an expression, without adding single quotes or the like.

I'm thinking *array_to_string* is part of the story, but not seeing any example of how that goes together. *Unnest* doesn't seem to be a supported function. My test below.

Or possibly in the DBManager as SQL, however I think my colleagues will not adopt that as readily.

[image]

Comment: Are the values always numbers if so you don't need single quotes. "targetfield" IN (1,2,3,4,5) will work.

Comment: Hey @Baswein that's a valid answer! Many thanks.

Comment: Didn't realise I was so close.     Now if you could consider a supplementary question, what if the array comes as space separated values, not comma separated?

Comment: I would have thought that this would work but it doesn't for some reason: "targetfield" IN(string_to_array('1 2 3 4 5',' ',',')  Perhaps because it comes out as a string. Not sure. Also tried "targetfield" IN(replace('1 2 3 4 5',' ',',')

Comment: thank you for having a look

Comment: @Baswein please add your solution as an answer so people can up vote it and BJW can accept it if it solves his problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the values are always numbers you don't need single quotes so simply using.

```
"targetfield" IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

In select by expression will work.

Comment: I am not getting consistent results, I put in say 20 values and QGIS selects 50 - 100. Not good.

Comment: That's strange. Are there duplicate numbers? Are they multipart geometries? You should be able to look at the attribute table and see what numbers are being selected and trouble shoot from there.

Comment: I've put the inconsistency down to something wrong with one install of QGIS.